# StackingCVClassifier pre-trained base models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I haven't been able to find any information on whether or not StackingCVClassifiers accept pre-trained models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. [`StackedCVClassifiers`](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/classifier/StackingCVClassifier/) and [`StackingClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier) currently take a list of base estimators, then apply fit and predict on them.

It's pretty straightforward to implement this though. The main idea behind stacking is to fit a "final model" using the predictions of earlier models.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Here `X_train` is `(750, 100)` and `X_test` is `(250, 100)`.

We'll emulate "pre-trained" three models fit on `X_train`, `y_train` and produce predictions using the training set and the test set:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV, LassoCV
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

# Emulate "pre-trained" models
models = [RidgeCV(), LassoCV(), KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=5)]

X_train_new = np.zeros((X_train.shape[0], len(models)))    # (750, 3)
X_test_new = np.zeros((X_test.shape[0], len(models)))      # (250, 3)

for i, model in enumerate(models):
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    X_train_new[:, i] = model.predict(X_train)
    X_test_new[:, i] = model.predict(X_test)
```

The final model is fit on `X_train_new` and can make predictions using `(N, 3)` matrices produced by our base models:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor

clf = GradientBoostingRegressor()
clf.fit(X_train_new, y_train)
clf.score(X_test_new, y_test)
# 0.9998247
```

Comment: Oh nice! This can be generalized quite a bit (e.g. implement the base models as `Transformer` objects so they behave with pipelines), but this should provide the basic framework.

Answer (score 0):

In scikit-learn you can do it passing `cv="prefit"` to the [StackingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html).

Make sure that the data you use to fit the stacking ensemble was not previously used to fit the base models.